# What is the difference between "cluster analysis" and "discriminant analysis"

Tags: nonexpert

From reading paper of [Clark-Murphy, 2010](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1207/s15427579jpfm0601_2), I saw the authors used two methods: "**cluster analysis**"(CA) and "**discriminant analysis**" (DA)

I found a great source of explanation [here](https://www.researchgate.net/post/What_are_the_similarities_and_differences_between_cluster_analysis_and_discriminant_analysis).
Essentially speaking, I understand the cluster analysis quite clear that:

> Cluster analysis is somewhat exploratory. It takes a data set and
> looks for the "best" cluster solution or grouping of the people based
> on their data. Essentially you are trying to find the "true" grouping
> pattern. Cluster analysis tries to maximize in-group homogeneity and
> maximize between-group heterogeneity.

However, in this link, I found a lot of discussion about discriminant analysis but I still not yet got the idea. Is there any intuitive explanation for that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi @Louise. Overall, cluster analysis (CA) and linear discriminant analysis (LDA) are dimensionality reduction methods. CA methods such as k-means and k-medoids are considered a type of 'unsupervised learning.' Here, these methods are unsupervised because they learn to classify data unconditional of a dependent variable. LDA by comparison is a type of supervised learning, which classifies subsets of data conditional upon a dependent variable. Alongside this, you will find that these methods are typically differentiated by the type of data you have available (whether continuous or categorical)

Comment: @EB3112 a geat explanation, thanks a heap, it is more clear to me now.